# How to implement 'Who is typing' feature via SignalR?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Basically I am implementing a SignalR chat in my website. I can already send messages to all connected users and now I hope to add the "who is typing" feature. I'm trying to add it in the `$('#message').keypress` function and it works but now I can't send messages to users.

What did I do wrong?

After remove $('#message').keypress can send message

[image]

Didn't remove $('#message').keypress cannot send message

[image]

My html
{

```
<input type="text" id="message" />
<input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" />
<input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
<label id="isTyping" />
<ul id="discussion"></ul>
```

}

Below is the script:

```
<!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.

        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + name
                + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + message + '</li>');
        };

        chat.client.sayWhoIsTyping = function (name) {
            $('#isTyping').html('<em>' + name + ' is typing...</em>');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#isTyping').html('&nbsp;');
            }, 5000);
        };

        // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
        $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
        // Set initial focus to message input box.
        $('#message').focus();

        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                var encodedName = $('<div />').text($('#displayname').val()).html();
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text($('#message').val()).html();
                chat.server.sendPublic(encodedName, encodedMsg);
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });

            $('#message').keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    var encodedName = $('<div />').text($('#displayname').val()).html();
                    var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text($('#message').val()).html();
                    chat.server.sendPublic(encodedName, encodedMsg);
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                } else {
                    var encodedName = $('<div />').text($('#displayname').val()).html();
                    chat.server.isTyping(encodedName);
                }
            });
        });



    // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
    function htmlEncode(value) {
        var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
        return encodedValue;
    }
```

Below is my Hub code:

```
    public void SendPublic(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }

    public void IsTyping(string name)
    {
        SayWhoIsTyping(name);
    }

    public void SayWhoIsTyping(string name)
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
        context.Clients.All.sayWhoIsTyping(name);
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On your server you'll have to have two methonds in your `ChatHub` with the name:

```
public void IsTyping (string html) 
{
    // do stuff with the html
    SayWhoIsTyping(html); //call the function to send the html to the other clients
}

public void SayWhoIsTyping (string html)
{
    IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
    context.Clients.All.sayWhoIsTyping (html);
}
```

How does this process work?

You catch the event that one of your clients is typing, that is with the keypress function from javascript. You then call a function from the server with your desired html, containing the name and other information. The server receives the information, process it, and then call a function from the client which does the trick of displaying who's typing.

In your case, your `IsTyping` method from server will handle the information which is coming from the client, and the `SayWhoIsTyping` method from the server will be calling the client to handle it the required information.

**Edit to your comment:**

I would advise modifying the function from javascript like this:

```
chat.client.sayWhoIsTyping = function (name) {
    $('#isTyping').html('<em>' + name + ' is typing...</em>');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#isTyping').html('&nbsp;');
    }, 5000);
};

$('#message').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $('#sendmessage').trigger('click');
    } else {
        var encodedName = $('<div />').text($('#displayname').val()).html();
        chat.server.isTyping(encodedName);
    }
});
```

and to remove the 
`$(document).keypress` function.

Comment: Thanks for your useful comment ~ i could send the "who is typing..." to all the connected user. However, I cannot send the user type message to the user. Did you know what happen? I have edited my code above ~

Comment: But if i remove the $('#message').keypress function, i could send those user type message to user

Comment: Usually, when using SignalR, server methods must start with capital letter, but when calling them from client, they should start with lower letter, that is
`public void SendPublic(string name, string message)`

Comment: Also, your keypress function tied to the `'#message'` element would overtake the keypress function from the document, which is the one who sends the message to the server, so whenever you'd press a key, be that enter, only the keypress function tied to your `'#message'` would be called. Look at my edited answer, it offers a combination of those two.

Comment: I have follow your guidelines but the problem still remain, is there anything i still missing? I have updated my question with images.

Comment: If you have doubts, check the browser console for errors. I personally tested your code, and it works fine when pressing enter to send the message.

Comment: I finally found my problem....because of i use    <label id="isTyping" /> instead of <ul id="isTyping" />

Comment: I'm just wondering about something with this, if the site is really busy won't it put quite a lot of strain on the server? Because every time someone presses a key it will make a call to the server?

Answer (score 2):

in the hub class  **Server Side**

```
public void UserTyping(groupName)
{
    var userName = "Get current user's name";
    //client method here
    Clients.OthersInGroup(groupName).OtherUserIsTyping(userName);
}
```

**Client Side**

```
<textbox id="message"></textbox>
<span id="userTyping"></span>

var keyPressCount = 0;

$("#message").on("keypress", function () {
    if (e.which == 13) {
       $('#sendmessage').trigger('click');
    } 
    else {
       // Don't want to call the server on every keypress
       if (keyPressCount++ % 10 == 0) {
        chatHub.server.userTyping("myChatGroup");
       }
    }
});

chatHub.client.OtherUserIsTyping = function (userName) {
    $("#userTyping").html(userName + " is typing...");
};
```